# How can I debug the speech in azure bot emulator? If I check 'open in debug', the directline fields are hidden and i cant enable voice

Tags: botframework, azureportal, direct-line-botframework

I wanted to debug ,the speech handling in my bot and add custom code wherever necessary. But after providing details of directline service in emulator, if i check the 'open in debug mode', then the directline credentials are removed and I cannot debug.

Screen shot of the emulator settings

[image: Screen shot of the emulator settings]

Answer (score 0):

Using the emulator in debugging mode ([Inspection Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-inspection-middleware)), you won't be able to use DirectLine Speech at the same time. Debug mode or inspection middleware is used when you want to use Emulator to view activity that is happening in another channel at the same time (for example Teams or Web Chat). Basically remote debugging (in a way). If you are wanting to debug the activity through Emulator, just run your bot locally in debug mode and use Emulator. You can debug the bot through the IDE and you can debug the activities, etc in Emulator.

Another alternative (I'm not exactly clear on your needs), is you can setup Web Chat to use Direct Line Speech, then use Emulator in debug mode with inspection middleware. I'm not 100% sure this would successfully, but a much more reasonable approach.